# How to design the classes for a simple shopping cart example using TDD approach?

Tags: java, design-patterns, tdd, ooad

I came across a shopping cart exercise to learn OOAD and TDD using Java.

The exercise is:

---

**First Step**: Design a checkout system

- Build  a checkout system for a shop which sells 3 products say Bread, Milk, and Bananas.
- Costs of the products are : Bread - $1, Milk - $0.60 and Banana - $0.40
- Build a system to checkout a shopping cart that can have multiples of these 3 products and displays the order total. 
  Examples are:
  Bread, Milk, Banana  = $2.00
  Bread, Bread, Milk, Banana  = $3.00
  Milk, Banana, Milk, Banana  = $2.00

**As a next step**: enhance the code to apply the below discounts and offers

Buy one bread and get another bread for free
 Buy 3 Milk for the price of 2
 Buy 2 Bananas and get one free

First build a simplest solution to satisfy the first case alone. Then re-factor the code to extend it for 2nd step.

---

The first step seems to be easy but when it comes to the second step, applying the proper OOAD principles and design patterns is challenging.
I took a look at couple of related questions like
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825619/shopping-cart-and-different-kinds-of-discounts-storing-discounts-in-db-and-appl). 
But it did not help much.
Appreciate any suggestions on how to go ahead.

The code I could come up for the first step is :

1. ShoppingCartTest.java :

   ```
   public class ShoppingCartTest {

   ShoppingCart cart;

   @Before
   public void setUp(){
       cart = new ShoppingCart();
   }

   @Test
   public void addOneItemToCart() {
       cart.add("Bread");
       assertThat(cart.getTotalItems(), is(1));
       assertThat(cart.doesContain("Bread"), is(true));
   }

   @Test
   public void addTwoItemsToCart(){
       cart.add("Bread");
       cart.add("Milk");
       assertThat(cart.getTotalItems(), is(2));
       assertTrue(cart.doesContain("Bread"));
       assertTrue(cart.doesContain("Milk"));
   }

   @Test
   public void addThreeItemsToCart(){
       cart.add("Bread");
       cart.add("Milk");
       cart.add("Banana");
       assertThat(cart.getTotalItems(), is(3));
       assertTrue(cart.doesContain("Bread"));
       assertTrue(cart.doesContain("Milk"));
       assertTrue(cart.doesContain("Banana"));
   }

   @Test
   public void addAnItemTwice(){
       cart.add("Bread");
       cart.add("Bread");
       assertThat(cart.getTotalItems(), is(2));
   }

   @Test
   public void checkOutOneItem(){
       cart.add("Bread");
       assertThat(cart.checkout(), is(1.0));
   }

   @Test
   public void checkoutTwoSeparateItems(){
       cart.add("Bread");
       cart.add("Milk");
       assertThat(cart.checkout(), is(1.60));
   }

   @Test
   public void checkoutThreeSeparateItems(){
       cart.add("Bread");
       cart.add("Milk");
       cart.add("Banana");
       assertThat(cart.checkout(), is(2.0));
   }

   @Test
   public void checkoutTwoSameItems(){
       cart.add("Bread");
       cart.add("Bread");
       assertThat(cart.checkout(), is(2.0));
   }

   @Test
   public void checkoutThreeItems(){
       cart.add("Bread");
       cart.add("Bread");
       cart.add("Milk");
       assertThat(cart.checkout(), is(2.6));
   }

   @Test
   public void checkoutManyItems(){
       cart.add("Bread");
       cart.add("Bread");
       cart.add("Milk");
       cart.add("Milk");
       cart.add("Banana");
       assertThat(cart.checkout(), is(3.60));
   }

   @Test 
   public void checkOutAnInvalidItem(){
       cart.add("InvalidItem");
       assertThat(cart.checkout(),is(0.0));
   }}
   ```

Shopping Cart.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ShoppingCart {

List<String> items;

public ShoppingCart(){
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void add(String item) {
    items.add(item);
}

public int getTotalItems() {
    return items.size();
}

public Boolean doesContain(String itemName) {
    return items.contains(itemName);
}

public Double checkout() {
    double total = 0;
    for(String item: items){
        if(item.equals("Bread")){
            total += 1;
        }else if(item.equals("Milk")){
            total += 0.6;
        }else if(item.equals("Banana")){
            total += 0.4;
        }
    }
    return total;
}   

}
```

Comment: There are too many ways of doing this. As mentioned in the question - your 2nd step would be to refactor your first step. Therefore, it would be much easier to narrow down, if we know how you implement the first step. The general way of TDD is to first write code (test) to invoke the given feature (which would obviously fail), then modify the application code to make sure the test passes.

Comment: @GurusharanS Agree with you. I will develop the first part of the code and share it soon.

Comment: @GurusharanS, I created a similar one, https://github.com/vksvicky/ShoppingCart

Comment: Well, The GitHub project looks pretty mature - are you facing any issues there? If so can you please tell what error do you face?

Comment: @Vivek Thank you for the detailed project. I am taking a look at it. Did you arrive at this solution based on TDD or did you develop this first and the added the tests?

Comment: @Ano, I arrived the solution based on TDD.

Answer (score 1):

Instead,  you can simple Implement shopping cart process as the HashMap in java

it will be of the form :

```
Map<String === itemname , Item === Item object>

Map<String, Item> cart = new HashMap<String, Item>();

Class Item{
private int count;
private String Name;
private int prices;
//getters and setters go here
}
```